# What happens when you set a map index, with a string index inside, to another string index value?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, hashmap

```
bool isIsomorphic(std::string s, std::string t) {
    //create hashmap
    std::map<char, char> ms;
    std::map<char, char> mt;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        ms[s[i]] = t[i];
        mt[t[i]] = s[i];
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (ms[s[i]] != t[i] || mt[t[i]] != s[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I was looking over this solution to a problem of finding isomorphic strings and I am having trouble understanding what is happening in the parts of

```
ms[s[i]] = t[i];
mt[t[i]] = s[i];
```

The string is never placed inside the map, but we are setting the map, with the index of the string to another strings index? I can't wrap my head around this. I tried this problem with just setting `ms[i] = t[i]` and comparing that way and it doesn't work. I realize I just don't know what is happening.

I would appreciate it if anyone could explain.

Comment: You're overthinking the syntax: `ms[s[i]]` is just indexing your map with a single `char` value.  That value is whatever character is stored at position `i` in string `s`.  So, if the string is "Yes", then your loop will iterate three times and store values `ms['Y']`, `ms['e']` and `ms['s']`.  Likewise, the value being stored is whatever character is retrieved from string `t` at the same index.  And so on.  You're not storing any indices at all.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution make `"abba"` isomorphic to `"baba"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first describe how we can check if two strings are isomorphic or not. According to [educative.io](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-check-if-two-strings-are-isomorphic):

> Two strings are isomorphic if one-to-one mapping is possible for every character of the first string to every character of the second string, and vice-versa.

Example-1: "egg" and "add" are isomorphic, where:

| Mapping of characters from first string to second string | Mapping of characters from second string to first string |
| --- | --- |
| 'e' maps to 'a' | 'a' maps to 'e' |
| 'g' maps to 'd' | 'd' maps to 'g' |

Example-2: "badc" and "baba" are not isomorphic, because:

| Mapping of characters from first string to second string | Mapping of characters from second string to first string |
| --- | --- |
| 'b' maps to 'b' | 'b' maps to 'b' |
| 'a' maps to 'a' | 'a' maps to 'a' |
| 'd' maps to 'b' | <del>'b' maps to 'd'</del> |
| 'c' maps to 'a' | <del>'a' maps to 'c'</del> |

Here, we can see characters from first string to second string makes one-to-one mapping, but characters from second string to first string makes one-to-many mapping (e.g., 'b' maps to both 'b' and 'd', 'a' maps to both 'a' and 'c').

Example-3: "foo" and "bar" are not isomorphic, because:

| Mapping of characters from first string to second string | Mapping of characters from second string to first string |
| --- | --- |
| 'f' maps to 'b' | 'b' maps to 'f' |
| 'o' maps to 'a' | 'a' maps to 'o' |
| <del>'o' maps to 'r'</del> | 'r' maps to 'o' |

Here, characters from first string to second string makes one-to-many mapping (e.g., 'o' maps to both 'a' and 'r').

So, the key here is both mapping from first-string to second-string and second-string to first-string needs to be one-to-one. By line `ms[s[i]] = t[i]` this code maps characters of first string to the corresponding characters of the second string; and by line `mt[t[i]] = s[i]` it does the mapping in the reverse direction. To be isomorphic, mapping in both of this direction needs to be one-to-one.

I hope this examples clear your doubt about the necessity of mapping in bi-directional way. You can even further improve the complexity of your code. You can find whether the two strings are isomorphic or not by making a single pass (instead of two). Here is the code:

```
bool isIsomorphic(string s, string t) {
    map<char, char> ms;
    map<char, char> mt;

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i+=1) {
        if(ms.find(s[i]) == ms.end() && mt.find(t[i]) == mt.end()) {
            ms[s[i]] = t[i];
            mt[t[i]] = s[i];
        }
        else if((ms[s[i]] != t[i]) || (mt[t[i]] != s[i])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You also do 2 look-up and have extra `if` in your loop. complexity is the same. Using `map::insert` would reduce look-up count.

Comment: As `char` has limited range, array might replace map too, see [my implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504311/2684539).

Comment: @Jarod42 I totally agree with you, my code have places for further improvement. Besides what you mentioned in your first comment, another potential improvement could be using `unordered_map` instead of `map` to make O(1) search/insert complexity. But, here, I just tried to show we do not need to make two pass over the string. My original solution for this problem was actually what you suggest in your second comment. As the char have at best `256` different values, we can simply use two arrays instead of the map.